# Jpanel inside Jframe with paint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, 2d

hi i'm triyng to do something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhyj3.png)

but i'm always getting the cross or in top-west or it doesn't appear and don't know why. I try to see the borderLayout and some stackoverflow explanations examples but didn´t find anything related. can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong and why please?

```
public Base() {
        super("Menu");
        JPanel p = createPanel();
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel P = new JPanel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                Graphic gr = new Graphicimpl();
                g.drawLine(gr.PositionX(-25.0), gr.PositionY(0.0), gr.PositionX(25.0), gr.PositionY(0.0));
                g.drawLine(gr.PositionX(0.0), gr.PositionY(25.0), gr.PositionX(0.0), gr.PositionY(-25.0));

            }
        };

        //P.setSize(50, 50);
        //P.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(300, 300, 300, 300));
        return P;
    }
}
public class Graphicimpl implements Graphic{
    int FACTOr_ESCALACION = 10;


    public  int PositionX(Double x) {
        return (int) ((x *  FACTOr_ESCALACION) + 320);
    }

    @Override
    public int PositionY(Double y) {
        return (int) ( - (y * FACTOr_ESCALACION ) +240);
    }


}

public interface Graphic {
    int PositionX(Double x);
    int PositionY(Double y);
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Base base=new Base();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `Graphicimpl`?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Use `JFrame#setExtendedSize` if you want to size the window to the full viewable area of the screen or Full Screen Exclusive Mode if you want cover the entire screen, `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` is just a bad idea.  Call `setVisible` LAST, after you have created your entire UI

Comment: To learn how to do custom painting read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html). Download the example and modify it for your requirement. That is start from a working example. This will also give you better structured code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of the cross depends on the coordinates you have inserted. Since you are inserting them manually. You can test the program with different coordinates until the cross shows where you want it to.